# How to remove white thick border from Wordpress gallery thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress, border, gallery, thumbnails

Site: http://www.ondrejmichalek.cz/rana-tvorba-early-works-1969-1982/

Problem: The thumbs of the images in gallery (I don't use any gallery plugin, just the native WP gallery) have this white thick border.

I have searched alot, tried various custom CSS codes but none of them removed the border.

Any solutions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.entry-content a img{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #fff;
}
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oh dear! Thanks alot! :-D